# find values from key,val object by giving its key

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am trying to find values from KEY,VALUE pair of object by giving the KEY.
The key is in array.

```
var arr = ["1398","1392","1390"];
var objects = { 1384: "registerItem", 1386: "createGroups", 1388: "vipNumbers", 1390: "targetNumbers", 1392: "ignoredNumbers", 1394: "globalConstants", 1396: "Users", 1398: "systemConfiguration", 1400: "applicationErrors" };
```

I need to find all the values from objects whose key is in array. How can i do this ?
So far I did this :

```
for (var a=0; a<arr.length;a++) {
    console.log(arr[a]);
}

for (var k in objects){
    if (typeof objects[k] !== 'function') {
         console.log(k + ", " + objects[k]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (var k in arr){ console.log(objects[k])}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#pick) pick method.

```js
var arr = ["1398","1392","1390"];
var objects = { 1384: "registerItem", 1386: "createGroups", 1388: "vipNumbers", 1390: "targetNumbers", 1392: "ignoredNumbers", 1394: "globalConstants", 1396: "Users", 1398: "systemConfiguration", 1400: "applicationErrors" };

console.log(_.pick(objects,arr))

//For Values
console.log(_.chain(objects).pick(arr).values().value());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: well, but iterating from objects side and then taking values is not a good idea, it is always better to iterate the array and use the object as hashing, and then performance wise. check my answer for that.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the value by `objects[ arr[ 0 ] ]` will return `systemConfiguration`

Where `0`, `1` and `2` are the key of `arr`

---

You can loop to find all. Like:

```js
var arr = ["1398", "1392", "1390"];
var objects = {
  1384: "registerItem",
  1386: "createGroups",
  1388: "vipNumbers",
  1390: "targetNumbers",
  1392: "ignoredNumbers",
  1394: "globalConstants",
  1396: "Users",
  1398: "systemConfiguration",
  1400: "applicationErrors"
};

for (var key in arr) {
  if( typeof objects[arr[key]] != 'undefined' ) console.log(objects[arr[key]]);
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to put "if(objects[arr[key]] != undefined)" logic in the loop.

Comment: in this case if the given array contains elements not existing in the object you will get undefined.

Comment: @Rainman: But what if the value of the property is `undefined`? Checking for `undefined` is not the correct way to check if an object has a given property.

Answer (score 1):

you can loop your array and then check if the current index is in your object:

```js
var objects = { 1384: "registerItem", 1386: "createGroups", 1388: "vipNumbers", 1390: "targetNumbers", 1392: "ignoredNumbers", 1394: "globalConstants", 1396: "Users", 1398: "systemConfiguration", 1400: "applicationErrors" };
var arr = ["1398","1392","1390"];
arr.forEach(function(entry) {
    if(entry in objects) console.log(objects[entry]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can i do this ?

Just use `map` method by passing a `callback` function.

```js
var arr = ["1398", "1392", "1390"];
var objects = {
  1384: "registerItem",
  1386: "createGroups",
  1388: "vipNumbers",
  1390: "targetNumbers",
  1392: "ignoredNumbers",
  1394: "globalConstants",
  1396: "Users",
  1398: "systemConfiguration",
  1400: "applicationErrors"
};

console.log(arr.map(a => objects[a]));
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to find all the values from objects whose key is in array.

In an ES5 environment, I'd probably use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), checking with [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) or [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) (depending on whether you want to check the prototype) to see if the object had the key:

```js
var arr = ["1398","1392","1390"];
var objects = { 1384: "registerItem", 1386: "createGroups", 1388: "vipNumbers", 1390: "targetNumbers", 1392: "ignoredNumbers", 1394: "globalConstants", 1396: "Users", 1398: "systemConfiguration", 1400: "applicationErrors" };
var values = [];
arr.forEach(function(key) {
    if (key in objects) {
        values.push(objects[key]);
    }
});
console.log(values);
```

In an ES2015+ environment, I'd probably use [`for-of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) instead of `forEach`:

```js
const arr = ["1398","1392","1390"];
const objects = { 1384: "registerItem", 1386: "createGroups", 1388: "vipNumbers", 1390: "targetNumbers", 1392: "ignoredNumbers", 1394: "globalConstants", 1396: "Users", 1398: "systemConfiguration", 1400: "applicationErrors" };
const values = [];
for (const key of arr) {
    if (key in objects) {
        values.push(objects[key]);
    }
}
console.log(values);
```

Finally, if you *already know* the object contains the properties and don't need a check at all, you could use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var arr = ["1398","1392","1390"];
var objects = { 1384: "registerItem", 1386: "createGroups", 1388: "vipNumbers", 1390: "targetNumbers", 1392: "ignoredNumbers", 1394: "globalConstants", 1396: "Users", 1398: "systemConfiguration", 1400: "applicationErrors" };
var values = arr.map(function(key) {
    return objects[key];
});
console.log(values);
```

...which in ES2015+ could be use concise arrow function:

```js
const arr = ["1398","1392","1390"];
const objects = { 1384: "registerItem", 1386: "createGroups", 1388: "vipNumbers", 1390: "targetNumbers", 1392: "ignoredNumbers", 1394: "globalConstants", 1396: "Users", 1398: "systemConfiguration", 1400: "applicationErrors" };
const values = arr.map(key => objects[key]);
console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try reducing the array, and either create a new object `{}` and take the `key,value` pairs for those keys which are exists in the object, or create a new array `[]` and keep pushing the values for those keys which are exists in the object. depends on your requirement.

```
arr.reduce(function(init, key) {
    if(objects[key]) { init[key] = objects[key]; };
    return init;
}, {});
```

OR

```
arr.reduce(function(init, key) {
        if(objects[key]) { init.push(objects[key]); };
        return init;
}, []);
```

and using `underscore` or `lodash` better to iterate from the array side and use the object as map, instead of iterating from object side, here you go:

`_(arr).map(k=>objects[k]).compact().value()`